# c# Unity Container Name

Tags: c#, unity-container

I want to get the unity container(created using Load Configuration) name using code.

Named container is loaded using config file and I need see the name of the container.

Is it possible?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I am not sure about this but just having way around of this problem. While registering the classes into the container you can inject the Container name into the class property so that while resolving the class you may access the property of the class which actually contains the name of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get name of container (*if you named it in config file*)

```
#region StaticVariables
public static IUnityContainer unityContainer { get; set; }
#endregion

#region StaticMethod
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var program = new Program();
    unityContainer = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();

    foreach (var unityContainerRegistration in unityContainer.Registrations)
        Console.WriteLine($"{unityContainerRegistration.Name } | { unityContainerRegistration.RegisteredType} | { unityContainerRegistration.MappedToType} | { unityContainerRegistration.LifetimeManager.InUse }");
}
#endregion
```

Configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>

  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IOperation" type="Unity.IOperation, Unity" />
    <alias alias="ILogger" type="Unity.ILogger, Unity" />
    <alias alias="ConsoleLogger" type="Unity.ConsoleLogger, Unity" />
    <alias alias="FileLogger" type="Unity.FileLogger, Unity" />
    <alias alias="AddOperation" type="Unity.AddOperation, Unity" />
    <alias alias="SubtractOperation" type="Unity.SubtractOperation, Unity" />
    <alias alias="MultiplyOperation" type="Unity.MultiplyOperation, Unity" />
    <alias alias="DivideOperation" type="Unity.DivideOperation, Unity" />
    <alias alias="QuotientOperation" type="Unity.QuotientOperation, Unity" />
    <alias alias="LoggingCallHandler" type="Logger.CallHandler.LoggingCallHandler, Unity" />
    <alias alias="LoggingInterceptionBehavior" type="Logger.InstanceInterception.LoggingInterceptionBehavior, Unity" />

    <namespace name="Unity" />
    <assembly name="Unity" />
    <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Unity.Interception.Configuration"/>

    <container>
      <extension type="Interception"/>

      <!--<register type="LoggingCallHandler" />-->
      <register type="ILogger" mapTo="ConsoleLogger" />
      <register name="ApplicationLogger" type="ILogger" mapTo="ConsoleLogger" />
      <register name="+" type="IOperation" mapTo="AddOperation">
        <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
        <interceptionBehavior type="LoggingInterceptionBehavior"/>
      </register>
      <register name="-" type="IOperation" mapTo="SubtractOperation">
        <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
        <interceptionBehavior type="LoggingInterceptionBehavior"/>
      </register>
      <register name="*" type="IOperation" mapTo="MultiplyOperation" />
      <register name="/" type="IOperation" mapTo="DivideOperation" />
      <register name="%" type="IOperation" mapTo="QuotientOperation" />

      <register name="plus" type="IOperation" mapTo="AddOperation">
        <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
        <interceptionBehavior type="LoggingInterceptionBehavior"/>
      </register>
      <register name="minus" type="IOperation" mapTo="SubtractOperation">
        <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
        <interceptionBehavior type="LoggingInterceptionBehavior"/>
      </register>
      <register name="multiply" type="IOperation" mapTo="MultiplyOperation" />
      <register name="divide" type="IOperation" mapTo="DivideOperation" />
      <register name="remainder" type="IOperation" mapTo="QuotientOperation" />
    </container>
  </unity>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```